# Why is my edited post count not updating?

Tags: support, edits, caching

On SFF.SE, I have made several edits recently, in the past few hours (I think around 20 edits). Before I started, my edit count was 155. Now it shows 156. Why has it not updated? (I know that tag wiki edits don't count.)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The posts edited statistic does not count edits that only edit tags. Since many of your edits are tag-only edits, as the screenshot shows, the count won't go up by much. In fact, you can confirm that only the last edit of those 20 was an edit that edited more than just the tags.

Also, edits to tag wikis and excerpts do actually count, towards both the counter and the badge. For details on the badge see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188732#188732).

Comment: And that one was a tag wiki excerpt edit, so that doesn't count either...

Comment: @Mithrandir tag wiki excerpt edits do count.

Comment: Not towards my badge... :P

Comment: @Mithrandir They do towards mine. See my [profile at Law](http://law.stackexchange.com/users/1344/wythagoras?tab=activity).

Comment: `Edit 500 posts (excluding own or deleted posts and tag edits).`

Comment: @Mithrandir tag edits are exactly the edits I talk about in my post that don't count. Edits to tag wikis or excerpts do count. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188732#188732

Comment: Ah. Now I understand. I thought that tag edits were the tag wikis. :P